# How to get the index of current element with a class name inside a wrapper element

Tags: jquery, html

Here is the html,

```
<div id="wraper">
    <div>
        <div class="test">1</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="test">2</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="test">3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="test">4</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="test">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`$("#wraper").find(".test").eq(2);`This will select the  3rd `test` class inside `wraper`.

I need to get that index(which I have passed as parameter to the `eq()`) while clicking on the `.test` div.

When i click on the div with class name `test` , i need to get the index of that div inside the `wraper` div.

```
$(".test").click(function() {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

this code will always return 0, as the `test` div has a parent div. So If I use `$(this).parent().index()`, it will return the correct index.

Is there any other alternative way to do this? Because in my real scenario there may be multiple levels of parents.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/349/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the 3rd version of [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) which returns the index of the passes item based on the set of elements on which .index() was called

```
var $tests = $(".test").click(function () {
    alert($tests.index(this));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/H24T6/)

Comment: thank you for the answer, Can i specify the parent also? http://jsfiddle.net/H24T6/3/ I need to get the occurence inside wraper div only

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(".test").click(function() {
    alert($(this).parent().index());
});
```

**Edit**

Sorry, I misunderstood the question. If there are multiple levels of parents and you know the top level parent for which you need the index, you can use:

```
$(this).closest('.some-class').index()
```