# Get index from different element group

Tags: jquery, indexing

I have list of `li` that contains 2 group of data, `data-type='a'` and `data-type='b'`, and order of a/b is random. How do I get index when user clicks on `li` only based one of the groups? For example, clicking 3rd `li` would return index 1 with html below.

```
<li>
  <div class='img' data-type='a'>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class='img' data-type='b'>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class='img' data-type='b'>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class='img' data-type='a'>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class='img' data-type='b'>
  </div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class='img' data-type='a'>
  </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 3rd version of [.index()](http://api.jquery.com/index/#index-element) which returns the index of the passes item based on the set of elements on which .index() was called.([courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157184/how-to-get-the-index-of-current-element-with-a-class-name-inside-a-wrapper-eleme) Arun P Johny)

Then combine it with attribute selector..

```
$("div").click(function() {
    var dataType = $(this).data("type");
    alert($("[data-type='" + dataType + "']").index(this));
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/g280xdcx/2/)